# NSAnimationContext for iOS

Tags: ios, nsanimationcontext

My questions are :

1. Does NSAnimationContext work in iOS ?
2. If the answer to question 1 is no, is CATransaction a good replacement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, NSAnimationContext is not available on iOS and yes, CATransaction is a good replacement. Apple describes NSAnimationContext as analogous to CATransaction in their documentation.